# Можно ли задать аргумент функции после описания самой функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def function():
    x = a + 10

a = 5
function()
```

Важно что одна из переменной, участвующих в функции была задана прямо перед ее использованием, а не перед ее описанием или в нем

Можно ли так? Спасибо!

Comment: да, так проверьте сами.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423839/python-def-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e/1423843#1423843

Comment: А что помешало взять и проверить?

Comment: @TypicalL L, а так работает ? Можно, но с умом.

Comment: плохая практика, привыкнете к такому - замучаетесь отлаживать код

Answer (score 2):

Нет, так не работает. Примерно то, что вы хотите, можно сделать с помощью функции, возвращающей функцию:

```
def plus_ten(a):
    def internal():
        x = a + 10
        print(x)
    return internal

function = plus_ten(5)  # Создаёт функцию, для которой a=5
function()
```

Answer (score 1):

Не понял вопроса. Это же ведь стандартное использование функций.

```
def function(a):
    return a + 10

a = 5
function(a)
```

Если по каким-то причинам вызов должен быть без аргументов, поможет частичное применение, реализуемое функцией `partial` модуля `functools`.

```
from functools import partial

def custom_function(a):
    return a + 10

function = partial(custom_function, 5)
function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать глобальные переменные. Лично автор не делал-бы таким образом с точки зрения свойства инкапсуляции ООП. Но язык это допускает.

Но глобальные переменные доступы на чтение.

Пометив переменную x как global, **можно обращаться** к ее изначальному значению, которое было определено вне зоны действия функции.

```
def sum():
    #Изменять значение можно только с помощью ключевого слова global
    global x
    x = a + 10
  
a = 5
x = 0
sum()    
print("Result: ", x)  # Result:  15
```